# laravel query: orWhere: double condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, orm

I have the following query, which does not give me the expected result:

```
    $query = $query->join('events_dates', function($join) use ($data){ 
                $join->on('events.id', '=', 'events_dates.event_id')
                        ->where('events_dates.start_date', "<=", date_format(date_create($data['date_end']), "Y-m-d"))
                        ->where('events_dates.end_date', '>=', date_format(date_create($data['date_start']), "Y-m-d"))
                        ->orWhere('recurrent', "=", 1)
                        ->where((strtotime($data["date_start"]) - strtotime('event_dates.start_date')) % ('events_dates.repeat_interval' * 86400), '=', 0); 
            });
```

There are 4 where clauses in this query. 
The requirement is that either the two first where clauses are executed, or either two last depending on the `recurrent`field.

PHP returns an error `division by zero`, because the last Where clause should not be executed when `recurrent`is `0`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't use PHP functions like `strtotime` on an SQL column in a where clause. Can you write it in SQL?

Comment: Possibly, have to look into that. Laravel seems to accept it though, I get an error on the division by zero. Doesn't it get evaluated first?

Comment: Hm, just realised that this approach isn't going to work at all. `where`expects the first parameter to be a field name in the database so I have yet to find another workaround. Ultimately I could isolate all recurrent events to a separate table, but I find it a bit silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your exact goal nor do I know what your db looks so this is just a wild guess:

```
$query = $query->join('events_dates', function($join) use ($data){ 
            $join->on('events.id', '=', 'events_dates.event_id')
                    ->where('events_dates.start_date', "<=", date_format(date_create($data['date_end']), "Y-m-d"))
                    ->where('events_dates.end_date', '>=', date_format(date_create($data['date_start']), "Y-m-d"))
                    ->orWhere('recurrent', "=", 1)
                    ->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(?, event_dates.start_date) % event_dates.repeat_interval = 0', array($data['date_start']));
```

#### Update

This might help for the between two dates part

```
->where('events_dates.start_date', '<=', new Carbon($data['date_end']))
->where('events_dates.end_date', '>=', new Carbon($data['date_start']))
```

Comment: I ended up migrating the recurrent events to a separate table and I'll join the results ultimately. I run the following query: `$query = $query->join('events_dates_recurrent', 'events.id', '=', 'events_dates_recurrent.event_id')
            ->whereRaw("ABS(DATEDIFF('" . $input_datestart . "', CAST(events_dates_recurrent.start_date AS DATE)) % events_dates_recurrent.repeat_interval) = 0");` Currently still struggling to do the check for all dates between given start / end date. I'll accept your answer for helping me on the way.

Comment: Thanks. It is a struggle, I'm not particularly good at queries. I have posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713474/get-query-results-for-date-range. In case you happen to know the answer, I will accept this as well.